# Data fetched from Firestore not showing in RecyclerView? (Kotlin)

Tags: android, database, kotlin, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore

It is a note taking app. I am using Cloud Firestore to store data. Data got added into database but recycler view is not showing anything. Below are the code snippets.

My Data Model Class:

```
   class Notes {
         var id:String?= null
         var title: String? = null
         var description: String? = null
         var created: Timestamp? =null

        constructor() {}
        constructor(id:String,title: String?, description:String?,created:Timestamp?) {
               this.id=id
               this.title = title
               this.description=description
               this.created=created
         }
    }
```

AddNotesActivity

```
    class AddNoteActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
      override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_note)

    btn_add_note.setOnClickListener{
        val noteTitle = note_title.text.toString()
        val noteDescription =note_description.text.toString()

        if(noteTitle.isNotEmpty() && noteDescription.isNotEmpty()){

            addNotes(noteTitle,noteDescription)
            Toast.makeText(this,"note added successfully",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show() 
            onBackPressed()
        }

    }

}


private fun addNotes(title:String, description:String){
    val currentUserId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.uid
    var note = Notes(currentUserId,title,description, Timestamp(Date()))

    FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("notes").add(note).addOnSuccessListener {
        Log.i("AddNoteActivity","Note added")
    }

}
```

}

NotesActivity(showing recyclerview):

```
    class NotesActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


lateinit var notesAdapter: NotesAdapter
lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_notes)
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rv_notes)
    
    setUpRecyclerView()
    
    floating_btn.setOnClickListener {

        startActivity(Intent(this, AddNoteActivity::class.java))

    }
}


private fun setUpRecyclerView() {
    
    val query:Query= FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("notes").whereEqualTo("id",FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.uid)


    val options:FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Notes> = FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Notes>().setQuery(query,Notes::class.java).build()

            notesAdapter = NotesAdapter(options)
            recyclerView.adapter = notesAdapter
            notesAdapter!!.startListening() 
}
```

}

Adapter class:

```
    class NotesAdapter(options:FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Notes>):FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<Notes,NotesAdapter.MyViewHolder>(options) {
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): NotesAdapter.MyViewHolder {
  val itemView= LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.each_note_view,parent,false)
    return MyViewHolder(itemView)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, p1: Int, NotesModel: Notes) {
    holder.title.text = NotesModel.title
    holder.description.text= NotesModel.description
    val date=DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM).format(NotesModel.created)
    holder.date.text = date.toString()

}



class MyViewHolder(itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
    val title : TextView = itemView.title_text
    val description: TextView =itemView.description_text
    val date : TextView =itemView.date_created

}
```

}

But when getting data from querysnapshot, logcat is showing perfect data from firestore database:

```
    val query = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("notes").whereEqualTo("id", FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.uid).get().addOnSuccessListener {
        val doc = it.documents
        for (i in doc) {
            Log.i("NotesActivity", i.data.toString())
        }
    }

     Logcat:  {created=Timestamp(seconds=1611116973, nanoseconds=14000000), 
    description=day, id=wLxCTMLGZpaWNs1b8Uhf3HoRUgz2, title=go}
```

I spend two days on this, but not getting any solution. I would be thankful if anybody can solve the issue.

Below is XML  file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rv_notes"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
     android:layout_weight="7"
    />

<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/floating_btn"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
   android:backgroundTint="@color/light_blue"
    android:src="@drawable/floating_btn"/>
```

Comment: First of all, use Kotlin data class instead of the Notes class you have written.

Comment: I also tried using data class but the result was same.

Comment: Can you share your XML file, it might be a constraint/size issue.

Comment: Have you tried setting the recycler view height to match parent (keep the recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this))?

Comment: I tried getting data from firestorerecycleroptions snapshot. It is returning empty string :like  I/NotesActivity: []

Comment: I tried setting recycler view height to match parent. Can you please tell why firestorerecycleroptions is returning empty string?

Comment: So the recycler view is displaying items but their content is empty?

Comment: Yes, content is empty. what could be the reason?

Comment: I think, It is firestore recycler options that's not working.

Comment: The problem is in  getting queried data in firestore recycler options. I am not getting data in options? Can you give me alternative to use firestore recycler options?

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot. Please respond with @AlexMamo